# VSTO Outlook: How to pin to ribbon a custom group

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

In outlook there is an option called "Pin to ribbon". You can access it by performing right click on a group on the ribbon menu and then a context menu appears, there you can select "Pin to ribbon". This make that group always visible in the ribbon in all scenarios, classic and simplified views and even when you minimize Outlook window.

So for my group I would like to do the same, pin to ribbon but programmatically. How can I do this?
I have got it by manually selecting that option from the Outlook but not programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Fluent UI extensibility model doesn't provide anything for pinning controls.

Comment: What is Fluent UI extensibility?

Comment: The Ribbon UI in Office applications.

Comment: Again, don't forget to mark the answer.